# YouTube PlaylistItems list for WatchLater does not return any items

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

YouTube PlaylistItems list for WatchLater (playlistId = WL) started to misbehave starting on November 26, 2019.
It started out of sudden, because previously working codewas working without any issues for months. I also checked for any recent changes in API - and last changes were two months ago (in September 2019).

It started that on November 26 it wasn't working at all, returning "Backend Error".
Then after some hours it started to pass again, returning OK result, but it returned Items array is always empty.

My request call is quite simple, results are same both in my app and trying in API explorer. I'm calling like this: [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B"part"%3A"snippet%2CcontentDetails"%2C"maxResults"%3A25%2C"playlistId"%3A"WL"%7D#examples_1](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A25%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22WL%22%7D#examples_1)

Was the issue with WatchLater playlist acknowledged, is it known? If yes - should it be fixed or is it still something in progress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to acknowledge that the [WatchLater](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchLater) property has been deprecated for quite some time.

**Update:**

According to [Google's staff response](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139525958#comment4) from Aug 19, 2019 22:42 UTC, there's no way to get the `WatchLater` playlist information from the API.

Comment: Hmm, strange than it's mentioned only in API for Channels.. Also strange that it was working without any issues until yesterday, because I see that deprecation note was on September 2016, so really quite ago.. (Link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-15,-2016). So might be it's a bit different thing? Do you know if there is any reason why it was deprecated, or might be there is another better supported way to get WatchLater playlist items now?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no insight into this issue. It may well be only a transient error, yet, by being a feature documented as deprecated, users shouldn't rely on it. I myself have no knowledge of some other way of achieving the same result; other SO users may well be more informed, so lets wait for their intervention.

Comment: Also, you may try to post this issue on Google's own [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). That way, hopefully, you'll get a qualified answer from Google's staff.

Comment: Ok, probably you are right. It was returning empty items lists for WatchLater playlists all this time. I didn't notice it because my app wasn't relying heavily on existing items in this playlist. I noticed the issues only when it started to fail with "backend error" (which was something temporary on YouTube site). Even though the answer didn't help to fix the issue, but it's correct answer. After all it wasn't obvious, because it was mentioned only in "Channels API", where I wasn't looking at all. So, thanks for clarifying! :)